# Is there a way for automatic user/answer magic link generation?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

I know we can paste a link to a question and it will be nicely converted to a title of the question being a link to it. I like to call it magic links, not sure if this is a proper name.

Is there any similar functionality regarding users and answers?

I ask because, for more than a few times already, I got a feeling of being annoyed at how tedious is referencing other users. Sometimes I just write @Nick, but I feeling like they deserve a link.

Same goes for answers to make it nice one needs to go for: [luk32](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1133179/luk32) and this is my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23364428/1133179) on [How to write output of terminal to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23364096).

```
[luk32](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1133179/luk32) and this is my 
[answer]https://stackoverflow.com/a/23364428/1133179) on 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23364096.
```

Is there a reason why such nice functionality was implemented only for questions? Or I just cannot find proper syntax?

One could argue it is not much overhead and syntax is not that bad, but you do need to copy-paste a nickname, and some are tricky. Moreover, a username can be changed, it could be automatically rendered.

Also, just a side-note, having some short form could be nice. like `[q:23364096]`, `[u:1133179]`, `[a:23364428]` for the precious space in comments. Is there anything similar?

Comment: Even as a mod, I very rarely have to link someone's account.  If someone wants to go to their profile, it's easy enough to find the comment to which you are responding.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I agree it is a rarer case and probably not worth the effort.  A situation I just ran into though at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756489/sorting-a-list-in-ocaml/23938814#23938814 is someone giving an answer referencing the OP by their user name in the answer.  Since then, the user has changed their name.  It would be very helpful in these few cases to update that reference to the user automatically.  I just deleted the reference because I think it is bad style to use `@somerandomuser` in answers and should be reserved for comments.